# How to run a command line script in qooxdoo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, qooxdoo

I would like to be able to go to a webpage select a few options and then run a command line script with those options. Is this possible with qooxdoo?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, but you will need a few additional pieces. You can create the web page with qooxdoo, e.g. using qooxdoo's form elements (qx.ui.form.*). You then need a backend you can submit the form data to (any old Apache will do, as will a Node.js server). In the backend you will need some custom code to create a subshell and run the command on it (e.g. with PHP, mod_perl, mod_wsgi, ..., JS), adding in the options from the web form.

Comment: without the form, how can I run a command line script, when a webpage is visited. Or a simple button is pressed. Let's say the script will always be the same.

Comment: The answer is the same: The web page has to notify the server, and the server can invoke the command line script.